# How to reload image in UIButton in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, reload, multitasking

I have a MenuViewController that loads when the app loads up; it is the root view of a UINavigationController.

Within the view I have a UIButton with an image that loads from a URL, as well as a label (its a picture indicating the weather and the current temp.).

Everything works fine, but if I am using the app on an iPhone 4, with multi-tasking, when the home button is pressed and then the app is reopened, I need the UIButton image and temp. label to reload.

I have tried calling this in my AppDelegate under applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
[self parseWeatherXML]; //re-parse weather data
[menuViewController reloadWeatherData]; //loads the image/label from the XML
```

with no luck.

I have also tried releasing menuViewController in applicationWillResign, then reallocating menuViewController in applicationDidBecomeActive so the viewDidLoad method gets called again, both ways just end up crashing my app.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT
Heres my method that gets called with the notification:

```
- (void)reloadWeather
{
[self parseWeatherXML];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:iconURL]]];
if (img != nil) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"setting image");
    [weatherButton setImage:img forState:normal];
    img = nil; 
}
currentTemp = [currentTemp stringByAppendingString:@"°F"];
[tempLabel setText:currentTemp];
tempLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
if([self isIPad])
{
    tempLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    [tempLabel setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 45.0]];
}

currentTemp = nil;
}
```

Comment: can you paste the console message here.

Comment: @robin I get EXE_BAD_ACCESS. I don't get it right when it loads, but after I press home and restart the app a few times. And the label for some reason shows MenuViewController when its supposed to say a temperature.

Comment: paste the console output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have your MenuViewController become an observer to the **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification** and perform the parseWeatherXML data. I would think you would be refreshing the data from the URL, so you would need to wait for that data to come back again. So, I would follow the same logic that you are doing when you receive that notification.

> **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification**
>
> Posted when the application becomes
>   active. An application is active when
>   it is receiving events. An active
>   application can be said to have focus.
>   It gains focus after being launched,
>   loses focus when an overlay window
>   pops up or when the device is locked,
>   and gains focus when the device is
>   unlocked.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>
> UIApplication.h

Comment: @bstahlhood I have implemented what you suggested as follows: 
'[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self         selector:@selector(reloadWeather)          name:@"UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification"              object:nil ];'
I placed that in the viewDidLoad method of MenuViewController. I had reloadWeather print a log, and it works 1-2 times (pressing home then reopening), but after 1-2 times it gets EXE_BAD_ACCESS. My guess is that reloadWeather is getting called after parseWeatherXML, which is called in applicationDidBecomeActive.

Comment: I tried putting the code up there in 's but its not working, sorry its a mess to look at.

Comment: @bstahlhood The notification method works perfect; I made the image and label not load a launch, only when viewDidLoad is called, which is only called when the app is reopened after it was closed once. So I know the notifications are working, but like I said once I reopen the app with the loaded images, if I try to close it again I get the EXE_BAD_ACCESS. Is there something I am not handling in the appDelegate? This error only occurs with the notifications code in there.

Comment: @Ryan Garchinsky Glad I could help :)

Comment: @bstahlhood I thought I had the issue resolved, but I don't. The method I call using the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification gets called, but it does not refresh the UIButton image or UILabel. Within the method I am first parsing the new weather data, which I print out in the console and it is parsing it; I also set the UIButton image to the newly parsed image and label to the newly parsed temperature, but like I said the old image/temperature still remain.

Comment: @bstahlhood I edited my original post with the method thats getting called. Also, the image and label get set properly on the apps initial launch, but after that they never set again, even though the method is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the image and temp using a plist or something, during the applicationWillResign, and then during applicationDidBecomeActive, you can reload the image and temp from the saved file/label. Just another option to explore.